# I don't know what to do about this: "ERROR TypeError: this.allCities.filter" is not a function, wthat means that "filter()" is not a function?

Tags: javascript, angular

I had to make an input that finds a name after an API. I did the filter method and  I have to deal with this error: "ERROR TypeError: this.allCities.filter is not a function". What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Although you really should post your code next time, for us not to guess, the reason is simple most of the time. [Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function):

> Maybe the object you are calling the method on does not have this
>   function? For example, JavaScript objects have no map function, but
>   the JavaScript Array object does

It means, the `allCities` object is probably not an array